# No sound after startup, have to alsa force-reload

Tags: sound, alsa

Every time my PC is booted, Ubuntu (13.04) is muted in the sense that it does not play any sounds. I found out that I have to type `sudo alsa force-reload` in order to get the sound working again.

How can I fix this issue, so that Ubuntu plays sound after a startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most complete answer I've found around is this one

http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

I've a motherboard ASUS P8H77-M PRO and the third hint worked for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes, this help me to solve my long standing problem. Thank you so much!! Change `RUN=yes to RUN=no` in the file `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` made the problem disappear!!

Comment: Upgraded from Kubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` having the same issue. need to `sudo alsa-reload` after every boot tried all solutions from the above link. #4 there is no `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` file. #5 my machine is HP-spectre-13-4003dx and my kernel is 5.15 > 5.4. any suggestions ??

Answer (score 8):

I recently updated Ubuntu and I had the same problem. I read many post on the subject, but I couldn't find a solution.

Finally I saw that when I restarted `alsa`, it killed `timidity`. So I disabled the service using the following command and bingo!

```
systemctl disable timidity
```

Comment: Thanks. Exact same problem after Ubuntu 20.04 update. I will chek to fill in an issue