# How can I fix having to type alsa force-reload after each startup?

Tags: sound, 15.10, pulseaudio, alsa

A while ago, I made some large update to my 15.10 that caused the sound to not work, such as in the question: [No sound after startup, have to alsa force-reload](https://askubuntu.com/q/303686/455520).

The accepted answer links to [this page](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/), which recommends typing `sudo alsa force-reload` and rebooting.

The issue is that I have to type that command at every boot, sometimes multiple times, in order to get sound. I've tried the other recommendations on that page, but to no avail.

Short of a `cron` job (because it's not ideal to automate), can I fix this issue once and for all?

Comment: This 2 y/o question has no accepted answer. Does the problem persist?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix None of the current answers were the solution, I'll write an answer and accept it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was eventually fixed by system upgrade to 16.04, and I have never seen this issue in any later version of the same Ubuntu installation through 17.10.

Comment: I have the problem in 18.04. Short of downgrading, I can't find an answer that works. :(

Answer (score 4):

If this problem occurs after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, it's not a problem in alsa itself but in the timidity converter.

Disable **timidity** and you won't even need to force reboot **alsa** on startup

```
systemctl disable timidity
```

Comment: What if I like timidity? Is the bug reported against timidity?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and try connect **SOYTO SY733MV Black/Blue (USB-Headphones)**,

*$ lsusb* - show next:

```
...    
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8086:0808 Intel Corp. 
...
```

and in  */var/log/kern.log*  show next error [**snd-usb-audio: probe of 3-2:1.0 failed with error -16**]  :

```
[34545.631107] usb 3-3: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[34545.632062] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[34545.632156] hub 3-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[34545.889431] snd-usb-audio 3-2:1.0: cannot find the slot for index 0 (range 0-0), error: -16
[34545.889437] usb 3-2: cannot create card instance 0
[34545.889443] snd-usb-audio: probe of 3-2:1.0 failed with error -16
```

I fixed error above performed next action:

1) updated alsa-base.conf

*$ sudo nano/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*

```
options snd_usb_audio index=auto
options snd_hda_intel index=2,3
```

2) unplugged USB headphones and execute next:

*$ sudo alsa force-reload*

After plugging USB headphones show next log:

*$ dmesg*

```
[ 6366.029686] usb 3-3.2: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 6366.120030] usb 3-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=0808
[ 6366.120038] usb 3-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6366.120043] usb 3-3.2: Product: USB PnP Sound Device
[ 6366.120047] usb 3-3.2: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.      
[ 6366.130665] input: C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.2/3-3.2:1.3/0003:8086:0808.0012/input/input33
[ 6366.186230] hid-generic 0003:8086:0808.0012: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2/input3
```

in *Control::Input device*

[new device: *USB Pnp Sound device*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttyjz.png)

3) set next in updated alsa-base.conf

*$ sudo nano/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*

```
options snd_usb_audio index=1
options snd_hda_intel index=auto
```

reboot system.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer, but did you notice the date of the original question? It's likely the user worked it out some time in the last 4 years.

Comment: Of course, but I think this answer can help to other users which haven't yet

Answer (score 1):

I only do ubuntu 14.04. But I have found no audio out problems are about the permissions given to /dev/snd and the files there. On my systems the files have permissions for user root and group audio.

Note no world permissions so a user must belong to group audio to have permission.

```
ls -l /dev/snd to see permissions.

.....@xen2[2145]ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Mar 22 17:42 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Mar 22 17:42 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Mar 22 17:42 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Mar 22 17:42 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Mar 22 17:42 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Mar 22 18:56 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Mar 22 17:42 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 22 17:42 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 22 17:42 timer

If your /dev/snd files have the same permissions 
grep audio /etc/group and see if you are in that group.  

I added my username to group audio with 
sudo usermod -a -G audio "myusername"
do not quote " your user name.

I use fvwm as a window manager and start gnome stuff in an xterm. Or Gnome-Terminial.

my quick test of sound
gnome-control-center sound see if the sound effect output. 
No then do it with sudo gnome-control-center sound and see if sound effects work. 
if it works for sudo or root and not for you then it is permissions.
```

Comment: I decided to look at file permissions of  /dev/snd.  Did some more research and solved my reboot loss of sound by using usermod to add myself to group audio.  sudo usermod -a  -G  audio    "myusername"

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

After that,

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Restart, and hope it won't happen again

Comment: I mentioned that "I've tried the other recommendations on that page, but to no avail." This is one of the recommendations; it doesn't work.